# Finding outlook mailbox size in vba

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I find the size of outlook mailbox in vba.

Comment: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/get-outlook-mailbox-size-from-vba.1556941/

Answer (score 0):

In case of an Exchange mailbox, read the `PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E080014`)

```
mailboxSize = Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E080014")
```